# If $\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert\leq k\Vert x-y\Vert,\;\;\forall\;x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n,$ then $x(t,x_0)=x_0,\forall \;t\geq 0,$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the following O.D.E

\begin{align}(1)\;\;\;\begin{cases}x'(t)=f(x(t)) & t\geq 0,\\x(0)=x_0\in \Bbb{R}^n&\end{cases}\end{align}
where \begin{align}f: \Bbb{R}^{n}\to \Bbb{R}^{n}\end{align}
Assuming that \begin{align}\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert\leq  k\Vert x-y\Vert,\;\;\forall\;x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n.\end{align}
Assuming that $f(x_0)=0.$ Please, do I prove that $x(t,x_0)=x_0,\forall \;t\geq 0,$ where $x(\cdot\,,x_0)$ is the solution of $(1)$. If there are references, I also would appreciate!

Comment: Any restrictions on $k?$

Comment: @Adrian Keister: $k$ is assumed to be greater than $zero!$

Comment: What I mean is, is $k$ arbitrary and not specified in advance? Or is it treated as a given?

Comment: @Adrian Keister: Although, not given but I assume it to be $k<1.$

Comment: Is the condition true *for all* $0<k<1?$

Comment: @Adrian Keister: $k$ is of-course $>0$

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear, because you aren't answering my questions at all. What I want to know is if the condition is: $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le k\|x-y\|$ FOR ALL $0<k<1,$ or is the condition THERE EXISTS $0<k<1$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le k\|x-y\|?$

Comment: Never mind; it doesn't matter. humanStampedist's answer is correct, and my train of thought erroneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ being Lipschitz means, any solution to an initial value problem is unique (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions)

Let us define a function $y(t):=x_0$, then $y'(t)=0$, since it is constant. We also have $y(0)=x_0$.
Furthermore $f(y(t))=f(x_0)=0$, hence $y'(t)=0=f(y(t))$. That means $y$ satisfies the differential equation and the initial conditions. Since solutions are unique, we are done, because then $x(t,x_0)=x_0$.